# How can I release a click-locked mouse pointer in OS X?

Tags: macos, macbook, mouse, mouse-click, touchpad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MacBook Pro Trackpad freeze / holds click on its own](https://superuser.com/questions/175378/macbook-pro-trackpad-freeze-holds-click-on-its-own)

Every now and then, seemingly randomly, the mouse pointer on my OS X 10.6.4-running MBP (summer 2009) will become click-locked. What I mean by this is that it acts as though I have drag-lock on, or that I'm holding down the mouse pointer.

I'm not sure how this is happening, or how the lock is getting activated since I have drag lock disabled in the trackpad system preferences.

I've not been able to reliably reproduce the behavior which turns it on, nor the behavior which turns it off. It seems that if I can get Spotlight to open and launch something like Calculator, then quit the the launched program, the click-lock will release.

Otherwise, the only way out of it is to reboot. This is super frustrating, as it's virtually impossible to save whatever I'm working on when the mouse doesn't work and seems to some impede keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Looks like we have the same problem! See http://superuser.com/questions/175378/macbook-pro-trackpad-freeze-holds-click-on-its-own

Answer (score 1):

I've never had this problem on my MacBook Pro, with the same configuration. I have a full load of stuff installed on it.

Since it seems like it could be a software issue, I would check all of the software you have installed - perhaps an app is causing the issue.

You could also look at installing [BetterTouch Tool](http://bettertouchtool.en.softonic.com/mac); it messes with the touchpad and I have it installed.

Comment: What a difference makes a good editor! Thanks @Gareth. :)

Answer (score 0):

The other way to get a click lock is with Mouse Keys in the Universal Access pane of System Preferences. If this is turned on, you can use the numeric keypad to move your pointer, and the 0 key is a click lock - press 5 to release. That said, I'm not sure how likely you are to activate this by accident, as the MacBook doesn't have a full numeric keypad - do you use the embedded one (used with the Fn key) at all?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I have a similar problem (http://superuser.com/questions/175378/macbook-pro-trackpad-freeze-holds-click-on-its-own) and have an external keyboard attached to the MBP. But Mouse Keys is disabled. I have "Enable access for assistive devices" enabled, though... Can this be the source of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem on my MacBook (13 in. Aluminum late '08) and the only way I could fix it is to do a little three-finger drag. The only way I have gotten to keep it from locking up is change the three-finger drag action to swipe to navigate.